# Request for giveaway swag and information for the B-Sides London and 44Con security conferences

Tags: discussion, conference, swag

I am heading to the B-Sides London security conference on April 25 2012, and the 44Con later on in the year, and as these two conferences attract a good range of individuals who should be members here (everything from penetration testers, technical security architects and implementers through to senior governance and risk managers) I thought I should request a range of swag to give to deserving individuals:

- speakers
- people who ask or answer good questions at the con who I can inveigle into posting them here
- minglers and high profile individuals
- etc

We got some of the attendees from B-Sides London and SF joining us last year so would hope to be even higher profile this year.

In fact, does SEI have any marketing material I may be able to reuse? B-Sides offers a 3rd stream which is a 'turn up and present' stream for short presentations. I could do a quick one on SecSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems super cool!

We're putting together a new Swag Request pipeline: just fill out [this form](http://s.tk/swagrequest) and click submit. Your request should be taken care of from there. :D

If you have questions or need further assistance, well, you know where to find me~!

Comment: hopefully that request is on its way, although there was no response message, just a blank screen afterwards:-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop Alex said it didn't come through :( Try again?

Comment: Got a response this time so all should be good. :-)

Comment: Yep, I checked with Alex and he confirmed. Looks like we're good. Now *accept my answer!* :P

Comment: ;-P of course I accept your answer

Comment: Yay! :D Youdabest.

Comment: heh - read that as Youdabeast - probably a denizen of Tatooine...

Comment: Or the Abominable Hoth monster :D

Comment: @RoryAlsop related to wildebeests?

Comment: Yay @AviD - how's you? You've been missed.